# Returning specific xml tag with erlang

Tags: xml-parsing, erlang

```
get_currency() ->       
URL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22GBPEUR%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys",
{Result, Info} = httpc:request(URL),
case Result of
    error -> 
        {Result, Info};
    ok ->
        {{_Protocol, Code, _CodeStr}, _Attrs, WebData} = Info,
        WebData
    end.

extract_text(Content) ->
Item = hd(Content),
case element(1, Item) of
    xmlText -> Item#xmlText.value;
    _ -> ""
end.



analyze_info(WebData) ->        
ToFind = [rate],
Parsed = element(1, xmerl_scan:string(WebData)),
Children = Parsed#xmlElement.content,
ElementList = [{El#xmlElement.name, extract_text(El#xmlElement.content)} || El <- Children, element(1, El) == xmlElement],
lists:map(fun(Item) -> lists:keyfind(Item, 1, ElementList) end, ToFind).
```

the above is the code im using to try to extract the contents of the  tag from the url http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22GBPEUR%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys.

here is what i do in the shell.

```
inets:start().
XML = scrapetest:get_currency().
scrapetest:analyze_info(XML).
```

and the return i get is simply "false". Im not sure what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add some logs to your code.

Eg. adding `io:format("~p~n", [ElementList]),` - will show you that ElementList contains only `result` tag, and you should go one level deeper in your list comprehension to get tag named `rate`

This is common advice.

In your case, seems that better decision is recursive find function (if you want to write some code)

or use some batteries, like xmerl_xpath

Just example for another `analyze_info` :

```
analyze_info(WebData) -> 
  Parsed = element(1, xmerl_scan:string(WebData)),
  xmerl_xpath:string("//Rate/text()", Parsed).
```

This will return:

```
[{xmlText,[{'Rate',2},{rate,1},{results,1},{query,1}],
      1,[],"1.1813",text}]
```